# Where did the negative reputation pop-up go?

Tags: discussion, reputation, notifications

I have been getting mixed up/downvotes recently, and I noticed that when I get a downvote, my reputation in the status bar (top right) goes down, and it shows in my profile, but it doesn't show as a red `-2` on the trophy anymore. Is this a bug, or a new feature, as I know when I started that it was a red popup.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's ever a feature.

Comment: It was, I just noticed it disappeared in the last three months.

Comment: Can confirm it was a feature for a while recently. Probably just A/B testing from a recent high-level exec saying to do it before a higher-level exec said no we don't like useful information notifications.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks, I was kind of sure it was a thing for a while. Grateful to you for clearing that up.

Comment: @JBDouble05 Features on SO sometimes only last a fortnight... this one I am sure I have seen before, myself. Though only for a while... I am quite familiar with the previous state of the system of *not* showing *any* negative rep effects, and then for a while (maybe a month?) I saw -2 and -1 notifications.

Comment: @TylerH So it was like a tested beta that they never really implemented?

Comment: @JBDouble05 I couldn't say, by A/B testing I mean random, experimental testing that the developers use to test certain features only with certain users... e.g the "A" group and the "B" group -- the A group sees one setting and the B group sees a different setting. This is a common method used by websites with large userbases/test groups to determine responses to new features without 'riling up" the *entire* user base with a potentially harmful change.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I'm new to Stack so I didn't know this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This feature has never worked this way; there is a [feature request on the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208900/295232) to enable it, but it's [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). The motivation for this can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/219665/295232):

> We want to let you know about good things as soon as they happen - that's what our real-time notifications are for.
>
> Negative reputation changes are... well... negative. So we are not in a hurry to let you know about them.

The score indicates not everybody is happy with this.

Comment: OK, thanks. I just though it was removed.

Comment: A negative score on a question/ or more likely: an answer is a some kind of feedback that I should change my answer or made a mistake. As downvoting does not always carry a comment about the reasoning behind the downvote, I might miss it until later. If I see a -1 I at least check Q&A and doubleread if something changed that made me deserve this.

Comment: The same goes for badges as well It seem I lost two but don't know which one and when and why?